# Typescript interface for constraining object based on key value

Tags: typescript, react-redux

I'm new to Typescript and have been playing around. I have this code that's getting an error (pared down for simplicity). It's ultimately for a redux action / reducer, which is why it's a bit on the convoluted side.

```
interface StoreType {
  bool: boolean,
  num: number,
}

interface PayloadType {
  key: keyof StoreType,
  value: ???
}

let test: PayloadType = {
  key: "bool",
  value: 3 // should ideally fail if value is not a boolean 
}

var obj: StoreType = { bool: true, num: 3 }

obj[test.key] = test.value // ts(2322) Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'
```

Two part question:

1. Is it at all possible to refine `value` in `PayloadType` so that `test.value` is of type `boolean` if `test.key == "bool"`, and of type `number` if `test.key === "num"`? I tried `value: StoreType[keyof StoreType]`, but wasn't sufficiently constraining :(
2. Is there a way to make the assignment `obj[test.key] = test.value` typesafe and error free? I've seen the error in https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31663, but I'm uncertain about how to proceed and I don't know if that's related to question 1.

If there's something fundamental I've missed, I would not be surprised.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Defining the `key` type in `PayloadType` as generic type parameter `K` with `keyof StoreType` constraint will do the trick:

```
interface PayloadType<K extends keyof StoreType> {
    key: K,
    value: StoreType[K]
}

let test: PayloadType<"bool"> = {
    key: "bool",
    value: true // ✅
}

let testError: PayloadType<"bool"> = {
    key: "bool",
    value: 3 // 
}

var obj: StoreType = { bool: true, num: 3 }

obj[test.key] = test.value
```

`StoreType[keyof StoreType]` does not work for this example, because `keyof StoreType` resolves to a union type `"bool" | "num"`. And a lookup of `"bool" | "num"` in `StoreType` will resolve to all possible return types `number | boolean` of these keys.

By declaring `key` type as generic type parameter `K` together with `PayloadType<"bool">`, you express that a specifc key of `StoreType` (not a union) is expected.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgPZQgFQJ4AOKA3gFDIXIBGGGANgFzW10RwgA05lIArgLZM+-KtC4BfUqVCRYiFAAU4eOhjgATfEQA8AaWQQAHpBDqAzsgDWEPBhhpM2LRAB8yMpSs2murp4BucHS8EEzoWLiEEADaugC6pJKkrGDIkGZgTEoqappR2gBENPQFbgC87twU1nhMRSwFfpSBwaFpUCHIAPRdyICg5IlSKWkQGQCiUFBYWcqqGs6FxXSlyBUelDV1S41VyC0hTADM3b2AvBuAxTuDpIFQyBhUAFZhjpFEq+7M9ExgHRAcyMIjsgkvcHtF0mAAHQ1OLvCGQ-YQIA)

Answer (score 1):

@ford04 looks as a good answer for the question you are asking, but not for a thing which your really want to achieve.

There is no reason (or I don't see it) for having explicit type info in your payload. I would say you are revealing some technical details in place where the domain data should be revealed. So for me it is wrong approach.

The sense in such would be to have discriminant in form of domain information:

```
type ActionType = 'add_user' | 'get_user' | 'add_comment' | 'get_comment' // example action types

// type constructor to save us typing
type Action<T extends ActionType, P> = {
  type: T,
  payload: P
}

// specific actions
type UserId = number; // just for convenience and readability
type GetUserAction = Action<'get_user', UserId>

type User = {name: string} // example payload type
type AddUserAction = Action<'add_user', User>

// action creator
const getUser = (id: UserId):GetUserAction   => ({type: 'get_user', payload: id});
```

Payload can be also primary type as you can see in the above example with `get_user` action. This approach is type safe, you cannot send `get_user` action with wrong payload type. Hope it helps.

Comment: You definitely saw what I was trying to do, and I really appreciate the example you've given—still trying to figure out Redux + types! Where the payload typing kerfuffle comes in is when I tried to make a generic "set" action, something like: `({ type: 'set_setting', payload: { key, value })` so that eventually `store[payload.key] = payload.value`. I was hoping to limit the possible keys to the existing ones in the store, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to constrain the value to corresponding to the key. Perhaps that's not possible and I should make my actions more specific...